# Can you chain GetElementById(...).GetElementsByClassName(...).GetElementsByTagName(..);?

Tags: javascript, html

for my school project i am asked to use:
`getElementById("id1").getElementsByClassName("class1").getElementsByTagName("h1");`
However when I use this nothing hapens and in the console of the html page the following error occurs: `document.getElementById(...).getElementsByClass is not a function`
The Problem here is that whenever i delete that third one in line everything works fine.

If someone can help me than i would love to hear your solution.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#id1 .class1 h1')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: `getElementById("id1").getElementsByClassName("class1")` Yes. `getElementsByClassName("class1").getElementsByTagName("h1")` No.